# building Web browser in Python and issue regarding cookies

Tags: python, cookies, pygtk, mechanize, mechanize-python

I know this sounds weird, but I have got no choice, I searched the google and I found nothing, So..

I'm following a video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JEW50aEVi4k on 'building a webbrowser in python', I was wondering if cookies can be saved, So is it possible ?
If yes, then could you give some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are not a problem - you can use mechanize (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/) which saves and sends the cookies automatically.

```
import mechanize
browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.set_handle_robots(False)

response = browser.open('http://www.youtube.com')

#Headers are handled automatically. You can access them:
headers = browser.request.header_items()
>>> headers
[('Host', 'www.youtube.com'), ('Cookie', 'YSC=cNcoiHG71bY; VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE=uLHsDODGalg; PREF=f1=50000000'), ('User-agent', 'Python-urllib/2.7')]
```

It is very hard to write a browser with Javascript support. If you need javasctipt then i suggest you to use [selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) with [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) which acts just like a real browser.